# 'arraycontaining' does not exist on type 'jestmatchers'

Tags: typescript, jestjs, nestjs

I write test for my controller in Nestjs. I expect an array of employees contains object `{id:1, firstname: 'john', lastname:'Dole'}`. So I write:

```
it('should get an employee', () => {
    return controller.findAll('john').then((data) => {
      expect(data).arrayContaining([
        {
          id: 1,
          firstname: 'john',
          lastname: 'Dole',
        },
      ]);
    });
  });
```

but got error `roperty 'arrayContaining' does not exist on type 'JestMatchers<Employee[]>'`
Shall I install additional package or update jest in Nestjs? I've install `"@nestjs/testing": "^7.6.15",`

Comment: Looking at the docs and examples you don't seem to be calling it right. https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#expectarraycontainingarray

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`arrayContaining`](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#expectarraycontainingarray) doesn't do any matching by itself, instead it returns a matcher that can be used together with e.g. `toEqual`, like so:

```
      expect(data).toEqual(expect.arrayContaining([
        {
          id: 1,
          firstname: 'john',
          lastname: 'Dole',
        },
      ]));
```